# Setting yahoo finance date as dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

i have a python function that stores the yahoo finance data to a dataframe.

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
bars= DataReader(symbol, "yahoo",hist_date, today)
```

and i get the result returned to bars as follows

DataFrame:

```
                    Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  Adj Close\nDate                                                  
                   \n2011-01-12  2.00  2.00  2.00   2.00     100   1.891661
                   \n2011-01-13  2.00  2.00  1.92   2.00    6800   1.891661
                   \n2011-01-14  1.84  2.24  1.84   2.19    1500   2.071369
                   \n2011-01-18  2.25  2.25  2.02   2.02    4300   1.910578
                   \n2011-01-19  2.07  2.12  2.07   2.12    3400   2.005161
                   \n2011-01-20  2.21  2.21  2.10   2.17    5000   2.052452
                   \n2011-01-21  2.25  2.25  2.20   2.20     600   2.080827
                   \n2011-01-24  2.20  2.20  2.12   2.18    2300   2.061911
```

now i want to make the date coloumn as the index field of the dataframe. also when i try to display the dataframe in a table i cant get the date field displayed anywhere. is it because there is a \n before the coloumn heading and coloumn data.

Comment: What is `print bars.index` ?

Comment: What does `display the dataframe in a table` mean?

Comment: I was trying to display the contents of the dataframe in a html using datatables

Comment: So you try `bars.to_html('page.html')` ?

Comment: Or maybe you want first reset index: `bars.reset_index().to_html('page1.html')`

Comment: I am more concerned about setting index to dataframe here. Html rendering is working fine

Comment: I dont understand, because index is set by default by `DataReader(symbol, "yahoo",hist_date, today)`. You can check it: `print bars.index`

Comment: Your code example is incomplete. Please provide a runnable example

Comment: Works for me with Pandas 0.15.2, What is your pandas version? pd.__version__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me retrieve 5 days of historical data for Google from Yahoo:

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
import datetime as dt

today = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
hist = (dt.datetime.today()-dt.timedelta(7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df = DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', hist, today)

df

                  Open        High        Low       Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                        
2016-01-05  746.450012  752.000000  738.640015  742.580017  1947700 742.580017
2016-01-06  730.000000  747.179993  728.919983  743.619995  1938600 743.619995
2016-01-07  730.309998  738.500000  719.059998  726.390015  2944300 726.390015
2016-01-08  731.450012  733.229980  713.000000  714.469971  2442600 714.469971
```

which shows me 6 columns for data: OHLC, Volume and Adjusted Close, and one column for index called `Date`

To ascertain that data frame is indeed indexed by date you may even try:

```
df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Does this short exercise address your concern?

PS
The ordering of column names and `Date` after Adjusted Close appears wierd to me...

Comment: ok, this is exactly what i have followed. now i want the date(index of dataframe) to be another coloumn in the dataframe so that it can be displayed like all other coloumns.  i tried the code
dataframe['']

Comment: @RahulRameshan To move index to a column try `df.reset_index()`